# How get html select > option tag custom attribute value using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

I have research that in html you can add a custom attribute by simply adding `data-*` attribute inside html tag. I populate my `select > option` tag from my database:

```
<td>
  <select onchange='setattr(this)' id='pitemnamerow"+ cnt +"' class='pitemname select2bs4 tselect'>
    <option selected='selected'></option>
  </select>
</td>
```

**My Jquery and already set my custom tag**

```
for (i in data.branditms) {
      $('#pitemname'+brndid.id).append($('<option>', {
      value: data.branditms[i]['item_id'],
      text: data.branditms[i]['item_name'],
      data-um: data.branditms[i]['um'], //custom-tag
}));
```

**DOM result:**

```
<select onchange="setattr(this)" id="pitemnamerow1" class="select2bs4 pitemname tselect select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="pitemnamerow1" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">    
   <option selected="selected" data-select2-id="81"></option>
   <option value="0-RKM51" data-um="PC/s" data-select2-id="84">0-RING 2"DIAMETER</option>
   <option value="UYD983" data-um="M" data-select2-id="84">Parts Wheel</option>
</select>
```

now when i try to access the custom attribute value it says undefine:

```
function setattr(brnditem){
    var test = $(this).find('.pitemname').data('um');
    console.log(test);  
}
```

**PS: My `table row` and `select > options` are also dynamic.**

Any idea?

Comment: You don't have any attribute with the name data. what's the value you expect to get?

Comment: i added it dynamically in my jquery.

Comment: can you take screenshot of your `html` tags in inspect mode and attach it to the question because I don't see attribute added name `data`

Comment: I have update my question.

Comment: I posted an answer @jzoler check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `data()` instead `attr()`, rewrite you code like this :

```
function setattr(brnditem)
{
  var test = $(brnditem).find("option:selected").data('um');
  console.log(test);  
}
```

Comment: i think there's something wrong with my code. I tried your code but still undefined. please see updated question.

Comment: I think you shoudl use `brnditem` in `setattr()` instead of `this`

Comment: $(brnditem).find('.pitemname').data('um'); still undefined.

Comment: how do you call `setattr()` and what do you pass as a parameter?

Comment: onchange='setattr(this)' i have included this in my question.

Comment: so I think we don't need `find()`, I've updated answer

Comment: @osmanrahimi, I wrote about the lack of the need for `find()`, but my comment was ignored, I deleted it comment.

Comment: let me copy your code into an online editor and test it

Comment: Im using laravel. anyways, my table is populated from the database and every select options inside the <td> as well. still undefined. :( or maybe ill try a different approach.

Comment: @jzoler have you seen the link above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225078/discussion-between-jzoler-and-osman-rahimi).

Answer (score 1):

Try checking this:

```
      var test = $(brnditem).find('option:selected').data('um');
```

also make sure the function was defined right before calling it on the 'select' tag

Comment: still undefined :(